# How do sum if the date is greater than 10 days from and including the upcoming Sunday?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have 2 rows. One row has dates and the other row has numbers.

I want to build a google sheet formula that allows me to sum 10 days after the next Saturday. So if today is Monday 7/22/2019, I want the sum from Sunday (7/28/2019) through and including the next 9 days. If today was Tuesday (7/23/2019) the formula would return the same result, because it's always starting from the next Sunday.

Another way I'm looking at it is the sum of the 10 days after the current week number since google has the weeks beginning with Sunday.

Thanks for your help.

My current array formula is using weeknumber:

```
sumifs(rowwithnumbers,weeknum(rowwithdates),">"&weeknum(today()),weeknum(rowwithdates),"<="&weeknum(Today())+2))
```

but that gives me the next 14 days, which is close but not exactly what I want. I don't want to sum the next 2 weeks after the current week, I want to sum the next 1o days after the current week.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(2, MATCH(VLOOKUP(WEEKNUM(TODAY())+1, {WEEKNUM(ROW(INDIRECT(
 "A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY())&":A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY()+8)))),ROW(INDIRECT(
 "A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY())&":A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY()+8)))}, 2, 0), 1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(2, MATCH(VLOOKUP(WEEKNUM(TODAY())+1, {WEEKNUM(ROW(INDIRECT(
 "A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY())&":A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY()+8)))),ROW(INDIRECT(
 "A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY())&":A"&DATEVALUE(TODAY()+8)))}, 2, 0), 1:1, 0)+9, 4))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Although you could put it all in one formula, I think for clarity and debugging it would be good to use a separate sheet (call it "Dates") for the date calculations.  Then use the results of the date calculations as arguments to your SUMIFS function.

In that case, the date calculation for the next Saturday is:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY()) = 7, TODAY() + 7, TODAY() + 7-WEEKDAY(TODAY()))
```

That checks if today is a Saturday, and if it is, uses today plus 7 days.  Otherwise, it just adds the number of days until the upcoming Saturday.  If you store that cell in B2, for example, then you can calculate your end date with a simple:

```
=B2+10
```

If you store that in C2 of the "Dates" Sheet, and your value list is in a Sheet called "Values" with dates in column A and the numbers in column B, then your sum function is:

```
=SUMIFS(Values!$B:$B,Values!$A:$A, ">= " & Dates!B2, Values!$A:$A, "<= " & Dates!C2)
```

Here is a link to a Google Sheet showing all of above: [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EXwumrEfb6xlhDfaPcYjEHPFt_k_iz0tK_SlUeJSkEM/edit?usp=sharing)